# Unable to start glassfish server in netbeans

Tags: glassfish

I'm starting glassfish 4.0 server from netbeans as `right-click-->run`. Further glassfish request admin password, i'm typing password, that spicified in `right-clik-on-glassfish-in-server-node-->properties-->password-textBox` but it's non-correct. When i'm starting using `asadmin start-domain` it's ok. Why to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are running Windows 7-64 bit or Windows 8

You have to use "Run as administrator" to run Netbeans.